# How can I force Chrome Beta to display in landscape mode?

Tags: settings, orientation, chrome-for-android

The default Android internet browser has an option in the settings to always display webpages in landscape orientation. Is there any way to do the same in Chrome Beta? I keep my auto-rotation off, but it's much easier to read webpages in landscape.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to have the Auto rotate feature turned on or off by app?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/110939/is-it-possible-to-have-the-auto-rotate-feature-turned-on-or-off-by-app)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a combination of [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm) and [Rotation Locker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.devasque.rotationlocker) you can keep your auto-rotation off but create a profile that sets the orientation for certain apps.

Comment: I ended up just using Tasker, as simply enabling autorotation when I launched Chrome  was enough.